# PetaPoco Insert/Update

Tags: mysql, petapoco

I have a table with the following field. I am not able to update the existing values in the table. I want to update it based on the SourceId which is not a Primary key (Id is the primary key). Below is the class representation.

I do not want to modify the PetaPoco.cs file. Please help. Thank you.

```
[TableName("Incident")]
[PrimaryKey("Id", AutoIncrement = true)]
public class Incident
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string SourceId { get; set; }
    public int AgencyId { get; set; }
    public DateTime? OccurredOn { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ImportedOn { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LastUpdatedOn { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select the record using the SourceID and then update it.
Example:

```
var rec = db.FirstOrDefault<Incident>("WHERE SourceID = @0", SourceID);
rec.AgencyId = NewValueForAgencyId;
db.Update(rec);
```

Comment: You should add a null check on rec, because if SourceID isn't found, it will return null.